# Search XML Document for Value and return Info

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to search the below XML Document for a 12 digit code refereed to as PLU. However much of my experience is with SQL when it comes to these things and I'm almost pulling my hair out with trying to get it to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<root>
  <Test>
    <PLU_Code>00000000000</PLU_Code>
    <Item_Name>Example Name</Item_Name>
    <Item_Size>1.1</Item_Size>
    <Item_Colour>aaaaaaaaa</Item_Colour>
    <Item_Gender>Male</Item_Gender>
    <Item_AgeGroup>Neutral</Item_AgeGroup>
  </Test>
```

The XML file just contains details of previously searched items. Now, I'm able to write the file without issues, however I'm trying to prevent repeated entries by checking if the items been searched for before. I cant seem to get it to work at all. My latest attempt is like this:

```
        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
        Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim str As String
        Dim fs As New FileStream(_PLUCheckHistoricXMLFilePath & "\Historic_PLU_Searches.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        xmldoc.Load(fs)
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("root")
        For Each nodes In xmldoc.SelectNodes("Test") 'This will be changed to txt box contents
            'each nodes is a Detail element
            MsgBox(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1))
            MsgBox(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2))
        Next
```

My main issue is searching the file and returning the information relevant to a specific item based on the PLU_CODE if possible, at least the  tag should be easily searched and retrieved, right?

Currently nothing is actually happening when I run my code. *And* it leaves the file open so it cant be accessed again. Can anyone help me,

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over all test nodes and there child nodes. Hopefully this will get you started.

```
    Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
    xmldoc.Load(_PLUCheckHistoricXMLFilePath & "\Historic_PLU_Searches.xml")
    For Each testNode As XmlNode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("/root/Test") 
        For Each detailNode As XmlNode In testNode.ChildNodes
            MsgBox(detailNode.InnerText)
        Next
    Next
```

If you desire, you can iterate directly on the details by changing the xpath to "/root/Test/*", and by removing one of the `For Each` loops.

Comment: Almost got it I think, how do I search for the specific value in the returned nodes? I'm trying:
MsgBox(detailNode.Item(1).InnerText)

Comment: If you are looking for things like "Item_Name" and "Item_Size" you can check the value of detailNode.Name.